# Disable alternatingItemColor property for AdvancedDataGrid if the rows are empty

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have a custom AdvancedDataGrid and we use alternatingItemColors property which shows two different colors for rows of the AdvancedDataGrid. Now sometimes the datagrid has 15 rows but only 5 would have data and we want only first 5 rows to display alternating colors and rest of the rows should only display one color. Has anyone done this in past and if someone can please explain how to do this would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the Datagrid and override drawRowBackground method, if the rowInd is more than the number of rows then set the default color. See the code snippet mentioned given below -

public class CustomDataGrid extends AdvancedDataGrid
    {

```
    protected override function drawRowBackground(s:Sprite, rowIndex:int, y:Number, height:Number, color:uint, dataIndex:int):void{
          var XMLdata:XML=rowNumberToData(dataIndex) as XML;                       
          if(XMLdata!=null){                  
                    if(XMLdata.attribute(Constants.col) != undefined && XMLdata.attribute(Constants.col) != ""){
                                    color=XMLdata.attribute(Constants.col);                 
                    }else{
                            color=0xFFFFFF;
                    }                                            
          }                       
          super.drawRowBackground(s,rowIndex,y,height,color,dataIndex);                 
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either set rowCount to the actual row count when you have fewer rows than the height allows for, or override drawRowBackground.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using Item renderer for your ADG: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var dpHierarchy:ArrayCollection= new ArrayCollection([
                {name:"A", region: "Arizona"},
                {name:"B", region: "Arizona"},
                {name:"C", region: "California"},
                {name:"D", region: "California"}
            ]); 

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG" 
                         width="500" height="500" 
                         paddingBottom="0" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0"
                         dataProvider="{dpHierarchy}"
                         itemRenderer="DrawAlternateRowColor">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name" />
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="region" headerText="Region" />
        </mx:columns>   

    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

</s:Application>
```

//ItemRenderer name: - DrawAlternateRowColor -- you can use the same concept with you CADG.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                                  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                                  focusEnabled="true" alternatingItemColors="[#0000FF, #FF0000]"
                                  width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:Label id="lblData"  verticalAlign="middle" text="{listData.label}" />
</s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
```